# HTML Input Capture and iOS Issues

Tags: ios, html, webkit

It seems that `<input capture>` on iOS devices only allow uploads of 480p. Has anyone figured out a way around this? If I upload from my camera roll ('Photo Library' on updated devices) I get a full quality upload. Straight from capture, very low resolution. It seems very strange that this works this way, there must be a work around.

Additionally, if there is in fact no workaround to this, is there a way to only limit uploads from 'Photo Library'? I cannot give the user any ability to upload sub-quality video.

Answer (score 0):

`<input capture>` does not allow you to set the resolution of direct capture from camera. I think this is a current limitation of that component.

The other way to accomplish your objective is through [Media Capture - Constrainable Interface](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-main/getusermedia.html#constrainable-interface) wherein you can declare your preferred settings.

```
const supports = navigator.mediaDevices.getSupportedConstraints();
if (!supports.aspectRatio || !supports.frameRate) {
  // Treat like an error.
}
const constraints = {
  frameRate: {min: 20},
  width: {min: 640, ideal: 1280},
  height: {min: 480, ideal: 720},
  aspectRatio: 3/2
};
```

But here's an informative reference in implementing capture with `getUserMedia()`: [Capturing Audio & Video in HTML5](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/)